# Rhythmbox refuses to maximize correctly

Tags: multiple-monitors, rhythmbox

When I try to maximize Rhythmbox in my laptop screen (Built-in Display), it jumps right back to my secondary screen (BenQ 21").

My screen setup:

[image]

Is there a workaround for this annoying bug? My monitors both have the same resolution.

Comment: It's not listed here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&bug_status=__all__&product=rhythmbox&content=maximize . I think you should report it.

Comment: Sounds like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/1176760. I doubt this is really a rhythmbox bug. Much more likely it's a compiz bug (it has had several bugs like this with other applications.)

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me from time to time and it's because my secondary monitor is bigger than the main one. Rhythmbox seems to preffer wide spaces...
My solution:

1. Unmaximize rhythmbox.
2. Move it to the primary monitor.
3. Resize the window until it's smaller than the monitor size.
4. Pres the maximize button (or drag rhythmbox to the top bar so it maximizes.